# Cannot find Sun OpenSSO installation

Tags: single-sign-on

I'm trying to get started with Salesforce SSO and SAML by reading this post by J. Douglas ( https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Single_Sign-On_with_SAML_on_Force.com ) , and I'm trying as well to download the Sun OpenSSO software, but I cannot find the final resource to download it! 
Going here https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19681-01/820-3320/gdefk/index.html , and here http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/indexes/downloads/index.html , I m not able to have to get the download! Any suggestions about where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Please go to forgerock.com.  OpenSSO is being discontinued by Oracle and Forgerock has forked and improved the product and named it OpenAM.